# Size difference between base class and derived class

Tags: java

```
int x=22;
long z=24;
//now in this case int is smaller than long so
z=x; // is quite appropriate as it implicitly converts from int to long(widening)
```

Similarly we have classes like this:

```
private static class Box {
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int length;
    //...
}

private static class WeightBox extends Box {
    private int weight;
    //...
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Box simpleBox = new Box();
        WeightBox wt = new WeightBox();
        simpleBox = wt; //we can always do this
        //wt = simpleBox cannot be done implicitly 
        //for this to work we have to use type casts
    }
}
```

Why is it that `simpleBox = wt` can be done even though simpleBox belongs to the base class and wt belongs to the extended class; shouldn't the extended class be bigger than the base class?

Comment: sorry my bad didn't see the block was not propely formatted was editing it but by that time u edited it

Comment: I have done no edits.  That word is 'you'.

Comment: yeah sorry sorry.i mistook you for the other person who edited it and would take care of chat language in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you declared:

```
Box simpleBox = new Box();
```

In this case, the "simpleBox" variable is declared of type "Box" this means that you can re-assign any object instance to it that is assignment compatible with Box.  At declaration time, you've given it a value which happens to be of that same class.

Since wt is declared as a "WeightBox", which is a subclass of "Box", it is assignment compatible (the liskov substitution principle mentioned above). It's no different than doing this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Both ArrayList and LinkedList are assignment compatible with List.

If you ever want to check this at runtime, it's a simple operation on the class itself:

```
Box.class.isAssignableFrom(WeightBox.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Size isn't relevant when considering casting. Check out this [tutorial](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/50451-upcasting-downcasting/) for upcasting and downcasting. Conveniently, it's in Java. :)